# Angular 6 how to pass selected checkbox to ngModel

Tags: angular, checkbox, ngfor, angular2-ngmodel

I have problem with pass selected checkbox (which is iterated) to ngModel.

```
    <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary" 
     *ngFor="let test of tests"  >
      <input type="checkbox">
    </label>
```

in ts I have model:

```
     testData = <any>{};

this.tests = [{
    id: 1, name: 'test1' 
  },
  {
    id: 2, name: 'test2' 
  },
  {
    id: 3, name: 'test3' 
  },  
]
```

I tried with ngModel and ngModelChange, but still have problem with display selected checkbox. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `[(ngModel)]="test.name"`

```
 <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary" *ngFor="let test of tests"  >
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="test.selected" > {{test.name}} - {{test.selected}}
</label>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yy9rfv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: But how to find check uncheck from here?

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you add a property in your model and bind it in the template.

```js
<label class="btn btn-outline-secondary" *ngFor="let test of tests"  >
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="test.isChecked">
</label>
```

```js
this.tests = [{
    id: 1, name: 'test1', isChecked: false
  },
  {
    id: 2, name: 'test2', isChecked: true
  },
  {
    id: 3, name: 'test3', isChecked: false 
  },  
]
```